# Blank node_modules in docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I have following Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:8.2.1
RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json ./package.json
RUN npm -q install
COPY . /app
RUN npm -q install nodemon babel-cli node-gyp create-react-app react-scripts babel-preset-es2015 -g

EXPOSE 3000
EXPOSE 3001
CMD ["npm", "run", "startServer"]
```

and docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "2"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    ports:
      ["3000:3000", "3001:3001"]
    links:
      [ mongo ]
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      [ "27017:2701" ]
```

When I got into web_container I've seen, that node_modules folder was blank. I've tried to change order of commands in Dockerfile, but it didn't help. I also tried to run "npm install" directly in the container and that was working, but I don't want to do this after each build. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the volume command in the compose file confused you. As you basically overwrite the whole project with your host one, the commands in the dockerfiles have no effect as the volume gets mounted afterwards and the content replaced.

Try running the whole thing without the volume section and you should see it working.

You can still use the volumes, but you would need to install the node_modules on your host machine then.

Comment: Yaa. Thank you very much :)